# Can a derivative be undefined at a local maxima?

Tags: calculus, optimization

If $c$ is a local maxima for $f(x)$, then can $f'(c)$ be undefined? Or does f'(c) have to be zero?

For example, is $x = 0$ a local maxima for $f(x)=-|x|$?

If a local maxima $c$ can be undefined at $f'(c)$, how can you verify that $c$ is a local maxima?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=-|x|$.

Comment: Math grammar lesson: one maximum, many maxima (or just maximums, which is also acceptable). Also, the function $f(x) = 1/x$ has no local maxima.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=1-\lvert x\rvert$.  It has an (absolute) maximum at $x=0$, but $f'(0)$ is undefined.

As for how to check: there really isn't any one method.  It depends a lot one what sort of information you have at your disposal.